# In T-SQL / SQL Server 2000, referencing a particular row of a result set

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I want to reference the nth row of the #temptable (at the second SQL comment is below). What expression will allow me to do so?

```
DECLARE @counter INT
SET @counter = 0
WHILE (@counter<count(#temptable))
--#temptable has one column and 0 or more rows
BEGIN
DECLARE @variab INT
EXEC @variab = get_next_ticket 3906, 'n', 1

INSERT INTO Student_Course_List
                SELECT  @student_id,
                -- nth result set row in #temptable, where n is @count+1
                @variab

SET @counter = @counter +1
END
```

Cursor (will this work?):

```
for record in (select id from #temptable) loop 
--For statements, use record.id 
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a while loop (with a counter like you are doing) to iterate the table you should use a [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Syntax would be:

```
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE c cursor for select id from #temptable
begin
  open c
    fetch next from c into @id
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
      --Do stuff here
      fetch next from c into @id
    END
  close c
  deallocate c
end
```

Comment: Iterating through the #temptable rows. Does the following syntax work with SQL Server 2000?

for record in (select col_1 from #temptable) loop

  /*Statements, use record.col_1*/

end loop;

Comment: @ppecher yes Cursor works like for each loops (but the syntax is a little more complicated, see my link to the msdn documentation). And they work with SQL 2000.

Comment: @JNK what would you suggest to iterate the table rows if not a cursor in SQL server 2000?

Answer (score 2):

Normally in a relational database like SQL Server, you prefer to do set operations.  So it would be best to simply have `INSERT INTO tbl SOMECOMPLEXQUERY` even with very complex queries.  This is far preferable to row processing.  In a complex system, using a cursor should be relatively rare.

In your case, it would appear that the `get_next_ticket` procedure performs some significant logic which is not able to be done in a set-oriented fashion.  If you cannot perform it's function in an alternative set-oriented way, then you would use a [`CURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx).

You would declare a `CURSOR` on your set `SELECT whatever FROM #temptable`, `OPEN` it, [`FETCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258896%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) from the cursor into variables for each column and then use them in the insert.

Comment: Thanks for the cursor summary.